# How to work localhost correctly? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, localhost, file-permissions

**Edited:**

My problem is:
Sometimes I need to run:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc;
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml;
chmod 777 -R var/*;
```

because sometimes I have problems with permissions on my localhost, I am using developer mode, and I would like to know if there is any permanent way to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on your command you are place your project in wrong location.**

**Change:**

```
sudo chown myuser:www-data /var/www/magento -R
```

**Into:**

```
sudo chown myuser:www-data /var/www/html/magento -R
```

**Or Else you do like this also:**

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/magento
```

I hope this will help you some extend.

Thanks!

Note: for better practice follow this document: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

My problem is:
Sometimes I need to run:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc;
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml;
chmod 777 -R var/*;
```

becouse sometimes I have problems with permissions with my localhost, I am using develp mode, and I would like to know if there is any permanent way to resolve this